# barplot 2 bars one stacked the other not

Tags: r, bar-chart

Despite some similar questions and my research I cannot seem to solve my little problem. Please forgive if the answer is very easy and I am being silly....I have a data frame

`df<-data.frame(X = c("Germany", "Chile","Netherlands","Papua New Guinea","Cameroon"), R_bar_Ger = c(1300000000, 620000, 550000, 400000, 320000))`

I would like to produce a barplot with 2 bars (Country names on x-achsis, amounts on y-achsis). 
The left bar should show Germany, the right one should be stacked with the remaining 4 countrys.

Please help and Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to solve this is by using `ggplot2` and a little bit of manipulating your data frame.

First, add a column to your data frame that indicates which bar a country should be plotted in (Germany or Not-Germany):

```
df$bar <- ifelse(df$X == "Germany", 1, 0)
```

Now, create the plot:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(bar), fill = factor(X), y = R_bar_Ger)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_sqrt() + 
  labs(x = "Country Group", title = "Square Root Scale", fill = "Country") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Not Germany", "Germany"))
```

[image]

Note that if you're not familiar with `ggplot2`, only the first two lines are necessary for creating the plot - the others are to make it look nice. Since Germany is orders of magnitude larger than your other countries, this isn't going to look very good without some sort of scaling. `ggplot2` has a number of built in scaling commands that might be worth exploring - here, I've added the square root scale so you can that the non-Germany countries actually do get stacked as desired.

The documentation for `ggplot2` bar charts can be found [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html) - it's definitely worth a read if you're looking for a powerful plotting tool.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to skin a cat, and your exact question will often change as you learn new tools. I probably wouldn't have set the problem specification up this way, but sticking as close to your data and barplot as possible, one way to achieve what I think you want is:

```
with(aggregate(R_bar_Ger ~ X=="Germany", data=df, sum), barplot(R_bar_Ger, names.arg=c("Other", "Germany")))
```

So what we're doing here is aggregating Germany and non-Germany figures by addition, and then passing those values to the barplot function along with sensible x-axis labels.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add an additional column to your data first:

```
df$group <- ifelse(df$X=="Germany","Germany","Other")
```

Then we can use the following ggplot approach

```
library(ggplot)
qplot(x = factor(group), y = R_bar_Ger, data=df, geom = "bar", stat = "identity", fill = factor(X))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks amazing and is exactly what I was looking for! I am still getting an error message but i think that has to do with my R Version. Will figure it out. This is a nice piece of code though. Thank you!